# Android studio real-time chat crashes when sending message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to programming, and it is my first time using Google Firebase.
My main activity seems to work fine. I can add chatrooms on the app to Firebase.

When I go into one of the chat-rooms I have made and sends a message, the app crashes. No messages is added to Firebase. If any of you guys take your time to read the code and founds a solution, I would appreciate that.

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button add_room;
private EditText room_name;

private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String>list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
private String name;
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add_room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_room);
    room_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.room_name_editText);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_of_rooms);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    request_user_name();

    add_room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            map.put(room_name.getText().toString(), "");
            root.updateChildren(map);

        }
    });

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
            }
            list_of_rooms.clear();
            list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
            intent.putExtra("room_name",((TextView)view).getText().toString() );
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    }
       private void request_user_name() {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setTitle("Enter name");

         final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);

    builder.setView(input_field);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            name = input_field.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
            dialogInterface.cancel();
            request_user_name();
        }
    });

    builder.show();}}
```

Chatroom class:

```
 public class Chat_Room extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btn_send_msg;
private TextView chat_conversation;
private EditText input_msg;

private String user_name;
private String room_name;

private DatabaseReference root;
private String temp_key;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

    btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_txt) ;
    chat_conversation =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
    room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();

    setTitle(" Room - "+room_name);

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

    btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();

            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);

            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",user_name);
            map2.put("msg",input_msg);

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);

            root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

}

private String chat_msg;
private String chat_username;



private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot datasnapshot)
{
    Iterator i = datasnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){
        chat_msg = (String)((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_username = (String)((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_username +" : "+chat_msg+" \n");

    }
}}
```

Here is the error from the logcat:

--------- beginning of crash

```
04-03 12:12:32.557 2493-2493/com.example.jens.rtchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jens.rtchat, PID: 2493
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahv.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahv.zzaq(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiw.zzc(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.updateChildren(Unknown Source)
   at com.example.jens.rtchat.Chat_Room$1.onClick(Chat_Room.java:69)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: add your logcat output please

Comment: I have updated my question with the logcat output

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you pass a `AppCompatEditText` into `updateChildren()`. That is not an acceptable type and you probably want the `getText().toString()` of that EditText control.

Comment: Thank you for help Frank! All I had to do, was to add the getText().toString() to the EditText control